# how do I use rolling window?

Tags: mysql

table t

```
send time           user
2016-07-24 12:00:00 a
2016-07-24 01:00:00 b
2016-07-23 00:00:00 a
2016-07-22 00:00:00 a
2016-07-21 00:00:00 a
2016-07-20 00:00:00 a
2016-07-19 12:00:00 b
2016-07-18 11:00:00 c
```

in this table, I want to count unique active user in the last 3days using rolling window.

on Jul 24th, count(distinct user) is 2. And on Jul 23th, the result should be 1.

and on Jul 20th, the result should be 3.

and I want to get the historical result at once.

how do I write the query in mysql?

Comment: what is rolling about it?

Comment: Great! What have you tried?

Comment: fortunately a rollback by Strawberry :p

Answer (score 1):

Using Drew's model, but with a correct query ;-p

```
SELECT DATE(x.send_time) send_time 
     , COUNT(DISTINCT y.user) unique_users 
  FROM t x 
  JOIN t y ON DATE(y.send_time) BETWEEN DATE(x.send_time) - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND DATE(x.send_time) 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(x.send_time) 
 ORDER 
    BY send_time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    send_time datetime not null,
    user varchar(100) not null
);

insert t (send_time,user) values
('2016-07-24 00:00:00',       'a'),
('2016-07-24 01:00:00',       'b'),
('2016-07-23 12:00:00',       'a'),
('2016-07-22 12:00:00',       'a'),
('2016-07-21 12:00:00',       'a'),
('2016-07-20 12:00:00',       'a'),
('2016-07-19 12:00:00',       'b'),
('2016-07-18 11:00:00',       'c');
```

query:

```
select date(send_time),count(distinct user)  
from t  
group by date(send_time)  
order by date(send_time) desc; 
+-----------------+----------------------+
| date(send_time) | count(distinct user) |
+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2016-07-24      |                    2 |
| 2016-07-23      |                    1 |
| 2016-07-22      |                    1 |
| 2016-07-21      |                    1 |
| 2016-07-20      |                    1 |
| 2016-07-19      |                    1 |
| 2016-07-18      |                    1 |
+-----------------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it needs to be rolling last 3 days, just do a `LIMIT 3` at end.

Please take the time to setup the data for people. Help others to help you. Pictures don't count.